# Simplified Object Data Source Control

Tags: asp.net

Is there any simplified Data Source Control that would allow binding to a local (code behind) page method? Any way to accomplish this with an ODS?

The ODS requires the TypeName parameter which I can't figure out to to point to the local page (code behind) in a Web Site Project.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListMain" runat="server" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value"
    DataSourceID="DataSourceMain" />
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="DataSourceMain" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetMyRecords" />

   protected IEnumerable<MyRecord> GetMyRecords()
    {
        yield return new MyRecord("Red", "1");
        yield return new MyRecord("Blue", "2");
        yield return new MyRecord("Green", "3");
        yield return new MyRecord("Black", "4");
    }

    protected class MyRecord
    {
        public MyRecord(string text, string value)
        {
            this.Text = text;
            this.Value = value;
        }

        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully tested but this does work. I need to test with UserControls and MasterPages. So, yes, it can be done:

```
public class LocalDataSource : LinqDataSource
{
    public LocalDataSource()
    {
        this.Selecting += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var instance = GetHost(this.Parent);

            e.Result = instance.GetType().InvokeMember(SelectMethod, BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, null);
        };
    }

    public string SelectMethod
    {
        get { return (string)ViewState["SelectMethod"] ?? string.Empty; }
        set { ViewState["SelectMethod"] = value; }
    }

    private object GetHost(Control control)
    {
        if (control.Parent is System.Web.UI.Page)
            return control.Parent;

        if (control.Parent is System.Web.UI.UserControl)
            return control.Parent;

        if (control.Parent != null)
            return GetHost(control.Parent);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Markup on the page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"
    DataSourceID="DataSource1" />
<ph:LocalDataSource id="DataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetNames" />
```

Code on the page:

```
public IEnumerable<NameRecord> GetNames()
{
    yield return new NameRecord("Andy", "1");
    yield return new NameRecord("Chad", "2");
    yield return new NameRecord("Jayson", "3");
}

public class NameRecord
{
    public NameRecord(string name, string id)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with an `ObjectDataSource` control. You can do it in the code behind though, by setting the `DataSource` property of the `DropDownList` to your object and calling `DataBind()`.